# C# Windows Store BackgroundDownloader to removable storage

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I am working on an app that will run on all Windows 8 devices (RT support a must) and I am working on adding some offline capabilities, but I can't figure out how to download to a removable storage device such as a USB drive or, in the case of a Surface RT, the micro SD card.  Ideally I would like to be able to have the user specify the directory, but it may end up downloading hundreds of files so it has to be specified just once, not once per file.  I also want to avoid requiring the user to manually configure libraries.

I have found plenty of articles about how to download to the various libraries, but those go to the internal storage and thus has very limited space on a Surface RT.  How can I have the user specify a location for a large number of files to download and/or download to a removable storage device?

A really slick solution would be a way to programmatically create a library in a location of the user's choosing so the user can choose if they want it on the local system or on a removable device.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take advantage of [`FutureAccessList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions.futureaccesslist.aspx). It allows you to reuse files and folders that the user has previously granted you access to.

First the user will select the target folder using a [`FolderPicker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.folderpicker.aspx):

```
var picker = new FolderPicker();
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
var folder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
```

You then add the folder to `FutureAccessList` and get back a string token which you can store for later use (e.g. to [`ApplicationData.LocalSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx)):

```
var token = StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(folder);
```

When you want to download a file, first get the folder from `FutureAccessList` and create the target file:

```
var folder = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList
                                                .GetFolderAsync(token);
var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(filename);
```

With that data you can create a [`DownloadOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.downloadoperation.aspx):

```
var downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
var download = downloader.CreateDownload(uri, file);
```

From here on proceed as if you were downloading to any other location (start the download, monitor progress...).